# Android Studio setting up AppCompat with separate resource folders

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm trying to learn how to set up appcompat and mess around with theming and transitions but I can't get past setup. Wherever I read it, they say to create a separate folder, values-21, for the material design themes but when I try to create the folder, it doesn't show up in android studio and any resource files I put in it from finder just gets pushed into the original values folder inside android studio. And if I try to use any sdk 21 items in there, android studio complains. Pretty confused as to what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Are you using the "Android" or the "Project" view in the project pane of Android Studio? This should be displayed on the upper right corner of the pane showing your folder structure.

Comment: @Tanis.7x im using android

Comment: clone & import this one from git ... https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is that you aren't familiar with the new Android project view.

The Android project view takes all resources of the same type (e.g. all `dimens.xml` files) and bundles them together. You can then expand that bundle as shown below to see the different variants of the file.

[image]

In your case, if you create a file called `styles.xml` in the `values-21` folder, you should see your default `styles.xml` alongside a `styles.xml (v21)` file.

If you don't see that, the easiest way to create the file is to right click on the `values` folder in Studio, and click New > Values resource file. You should then see a dialog similar to the one below. Put in the name of the file you want to create, and either manually put in the director or use the resource qualifier selector to let the dialog pick the correct folder for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the projects pane, instead of 'Android' choose 'Project' from the drop-down.

After this if you navigate to your 'res' folder, you should have the values and values-21 as separate folders by default.